# getting error while adding cmp "You cannot have device specific size attributes for <lightning-layout-item> component without specifying the size attr

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, error

```
<template>
<template if:true={apartmentFound}>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <template for:each={apartments} for:item="apart">
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" key={apart.id} size="6">
                    <lightning-layout key={apart.id} multiple-rows>
                        <div key={apart.id} class="slds-box" style="width: 100%; background-color:white" >
                            <lightning-layout>
                                <lightning-layout-item size="8" padding="around-small">
                                    <lightning-card title={apart.Name}>
                                        <lightning-layout-item style="color: brown" padding="around-small" small-device-size="6"
                                        medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="6">  <!--edit-->
                                            USD:{apart.Expected_Rent__c}
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" small-device-size="6"
                                        medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="6">
                                            Apartment Number:{apart.Apartment_Number__c}
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" small-device-size="6"
                                        medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="6">
                                            Number of Baths:{apart.Baths__c}
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" small-device-size="6"
                                        medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="6">
                                            Building Name:S{apart.Building_Name__c}
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" small-device-size="6"
                                        medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="6">
                                            Duration of Rent:{apart.Duration_of_Rent__c}
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" small-device-size="6"
                                        medium-device-size="6" large-device-size="6">
                                            No. of Bedroom:{apart.No_of_Bedroom__c}
                                        </lightning-layout-item>
                                    </lightning-card>
                                    <div class="slds-p-top_small">    <!--edit-->
                                        <lightning-button-group>
                                            <lightning-button label="Owner Details" variant="brand"></lightning-button>
                                            <lightning-button label="Apartment Details " variant="brand" value={apart.ID}></lightning-button>
                                            <lightning-button label="Contract" variant="brand"></lightning-button>
                                        </lightning-button-group>
                                    </div>
                                </lightning-layout-item>
                            </lightning-layout>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-layout>
                </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
<template if:false={apartmentFound}>
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-form-element slds-color-picker__summary" style="height:5rem">
        No apartment found.
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you can't specify `small-device-size`, `medium-device-size`, or `large-device-size` without also specifying `size`. In addition, since you're already specifying all three as the same size, that's the same as just saying `size="6"`. There's no need to specify each size individually when you're only using one size. If you decide you want to specify different sizes later, you can always add in those additional attributes. You can consider `size` to be the default size for any unspecified device size.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved.